# How can i calculate the frustrum rectangle of a camera, at a given distance?

Tags: computer-vision

I have a camera in 3D space, at position x=0, y=0, z=0.

The focal length is 16mm.

The image resolution is 1920 x 1080.

The sensor size is 21.12 x 11.88.

I have a 2D rectangular plane in front of the camera, at a distance of 5 meters. Its size matches the image resolution (1920 x 1080)

What i want to do is calculate the size of the camera frustrum at this given distance, and scale my rectangle to fill it exactly.

When the focal length changes, I will need to adjust the scale of the rectangle accordingly.

In this image, how can i calculate the size of the grey rectangle from the data above?

[image]

Comment: 21.12 x 11.88 what? mm?

Comment: Sorry, yes, mm.

Answer (score -1):

Pixel ratio: pr = 1920/21.12 pixel/mm

Plane distance in pixels: d = 5 * 1.0e3 mm * pr

Plane scale: S = d / 16 * 1920